# ColdFusion Websocket subscribe() JavaScript not working when called on page load

Tags: jquery, websocket, coldfusion

I have a basic ColdFusion page that uses websockets to subscribe to a channel, and then display/publish messages, i.e. a very crude chat application.

The code can be seen below.

Here's the problem: When I click the Subscribe button and call `SubscribeToChannel()`, the user subscribes to the channel successfully and everything works perfectly. When I Send a Message, the websocket publishes it just fine. (As indicated by the comment numbered 2)

However, when I call the `SubscribeToChannel()` on document ready, the function gets called, but the user does not appear to be subscribed, as every time I publish a message, it does not appear. (As indicated by the comment numbered 1)

So, `SubscribeToChannel()` works when called via the button click, but not the `$(function) document ready` process. Why?

I would like the user to be subscribed on page load, not have to click a button to initiate the subscription.

> (Please note, I am NOT looking to use the `SubscribeTo` attribute of
>   the cfwebsocket tag, as it does not allow for custom parameters. )

```
<cfwebsocket
  name="chatWS"
  secure="true"
  onMessage="messageHandler"/>
<doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script
            src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"
            integrity="sha256-cCueBR6CsyA4/9szpPfrX3s49M9vUU5BgtiJj06wt/s="
            crossorigin="anonymous">
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            function subscribeToChannel()
            {
                alert('subscribing');
                chatWS.subscribe("chat", messageHandler);
            }

            messageHandler =  function(aEvent,aToken) {
                if (aEvent.data) {
                    $( "#myChatArea" ).append( aEvent.data  + "<br />");
                }
            }

            sendMessage = function() {
                var msg2Send = $( "#myMessage" ).val();
                if (msg2Send) {
                    chatWS.publish("chat", msg2Send);
                }
            }

            $(function(){
                <!--- 1) Subscribe DOES NOT WORK when called on page ready --->
                subscribeToChannel();
            });

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="myChatArea"><cfoutput>#Application.chatHistory#</cfoutput></div>
        <input type="text" id="myMessage" /><input id="myButton" type="button" value="Send Message" onClick="sendMessage()" />
        <input id="subscribe" type="button" value="Subscribe" onClick="subscribeToChannel()" />
        <!--- 2) Subscribe WORKS when called via this button --->
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sounds like it's just a simple race condition, if it works on click but not dom ready. If only there were documentation that told you how this all works on a deeper level.

Comment: Have you tried using the `onOpen` attribute of the `cfwebsocket` tag? I'm thinking the DOM may be loaded but the websocket connection may not be established yet. The `onOpen` attribute is supposed to give you a way of calling a JavaScript function when the websocket establishes a connection.

Comment: @Miguel-F: Thanks, it turns out that the onOpen event does in fact fire AFTER all other DOM related events have fired. So this worked perfectly! Feel free to add it as a solution below so that I can accept it as the correct answer. Thanks again!

Comment: Cool, glad that worked for you. I will add an answer so others can see it more prominently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*promoted from the comments*

Have you tried using the `onOpen` attribute of the `cfwebsocket` tag? I'm thinking the DOM may be loaded but the websocket connection may not be established yet. The `onOpen` attribute is supposed to give you a way of calling a JavaScript function **after** the websocket establishes a connection.

From the [documentation](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-u-z/cfwebsocket.html):

> onOpen  -  Optional  -  The JavaScript function that is called when the WebSocket establishes a connection.

Adding to your code example:

```
<cfwebsocket
  name="chatWS"
  secure="true"
  onMessage="messageHandler"
  onOpen="openHandler" />
<doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script
        src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-cCueBR6CsyA4/9szpPfrX3s49M9vUU5BgtiJj06wt/s="
        crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function subscribeToChannel()
        {
            alert('subscribing');
            chatWS.subscribe("chat", messageHandler);
        }

        messageHandler =  function(aEvent,aToken) {
            if (aEvent.data) {
                $( "#myChatArea" ).append( aEvent.data  + "<br />");
            }
        }

        openHandler =  function() {
            subscribeToChannel();
        }


       // the rest of your code here ...
```

Comment: Thanks, it turns out that the onOpen event does in fact fire AFTER all other DOM related events have fired. So this worked perfectly!